# React js website is thowing error on refresh?

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I'm reposting this with more information, this is driving me crazy so any help is appreciated. I've created a website with react (node.js) and deployed it.

I have 3 pages on my website and they all work fine (using react-router-dom for navigation) except for a really strange issue when I refresh 2 of the pages (all pages except home page) I get this error message:

*Not Found
The requested URL was not found on this server.
Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.*

When I google this people say that a ".htaccess" file is needed with some extra lines but I'm a beginner to react js so I don't know what this means or how/where to create one. Can someone help me with this?

Thank you!!

```
App.js
import { Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Home/>}/>
        <Route path="/about" element={<About/>}/>
        <Route path="/work" element={<Work/>}/>
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Please provide some code to reproduce the issue

Comment: Yes but what code? From App.js?

Comment: Webservers traditionally serve files, for example `index.html`. With single page apps, we often use fake URLs like `/myroute/stuff` that don't belong to an actual file on the web host. The react app is meant to catch these URLs and render the corresponding route. To make this work, the web server is configured to still serve `index.html` (containing the react single page app) in case of errors like 404 not found. So this is a setting that every web server hosting single page apps with custom URLs needs.

Comment: Thank you @timotgl , how would I resolve this issue?

Comment: It depends on the web server/environment you're using. It is such a common configuration that your web host should have documentation for that somewhere.

Comment: Ahh okay, so I should contact them for this problem? I thought it was in my code but then they can add it for me?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React-router URLs don't work when refreshing or writing manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928372/react-router-urls-dont-work-when-refreshing-or-writing-manually)

Comment: `ErrorDocument` implies that you might be using Apache. So a `.htaccess` file is probably the way to go. That or modifying the apache config itself.

Comment: But .htaccess is a file that I will get through my web host? Or is it something I need to create and implement myself? thank you!

Comment: It is a file you write (it's only a few lines) and place on your web space, usually via FTP or through some other upload/deployment functionality.

Comment: You can avoid these issues by using hash routes btw. The URLs just won't be as pretty, you will always have `index.html` in them.

Comment: Okay so I'll write it in VSC and then just add it in my build-upload? sorry for 1000 questions I'm just super confused about how to fix this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so don't know if this will help anyone but this solved it:

- log into cpanel
- create a file under public html under file manager
- name it .htaccess
- paste this:

  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]

voila! (hopefully)

Comment: It doesn't work if there is Node ExpressJs running on backend.

Answer (score -2):

TBH, this one is kind of a hack. Have you ever seen those URLs with # in them? They're using Hash History.

The idea is by appending a # to the end of the root of your URL, anything after that # won't be sent to the server. So if the URL was https://ui.dev/#/courses, the browser would make a GET request to https://ui.dev, get back all the JavaScript, React Router would then load, see /courses, and show the proper view for that route. React Router provides a HashRouter component you could use that will get you hash-based routing, but honestly, unless you REALLY need it, there are better options.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).